# How did Nog beat the Kobayashi Maru?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-eu, kobayashi-maru

From the Memory Alpha article on [Nog](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nog):

> Nog's time at the Academy is featured in the "Star Trek: Starfleet Academy" comic book series, where he's one of the main characters. In the short story "The Bottom Line" in the Strange New Worlds anthology, we see how he handles the famous Kobayashi Maru test.

And from the [Kobayashi Maru](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru_scenario) page:

> Cadet Nog solves it [The Kobayashi Maru] in two entirely different (and thoroughly Ferengi) ways.

But neither article describes the way in which he solves the test.

How did Nog handle the Kobayashi Maru?

Comment: 1. Bribe a computer technician. 2. Bribe another computer technician.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite On Earth?  Which has canonically been referred to as a paradise?  What would he have to bribe them *with*?

Comment: "C'mon, do me a favor.  I can get you a copy of my uncle's best holosuite programs."  Or, possibly, the computer techs needed baseball cards.

Comment: @Zibbobz - having lived in a socialist paradise, I can fully and totally confirm that people there are MORE succeptible to bribery than the evil money-grubbing capitalists.

Comment: @Zibbobz Remember the [Great Material Continuum](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Treachery,_Faith_and_the_Great_River_%28episode%29)?  There's always _something_

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'm not sure which order they come, but as far as publishing dates, the first victory was in *The Bottom Line*, which was printed in "Strange New Worlds III". This was the more interesting of the two -- purely tactical as far as I can tell. Although whether he won or not is somewhat dubious. With the tractor beam, he slingshots the Kobayashi Maru towards the border, and then engages with (in this simulation) the Cardassians in battle. He then signals his surrender and shuts down systems. When they began boarding the ship:

> Nog rushed to his chair and triggered "the bottom line."
>
> "Five seconds to auto-destruct," the ship's computer announced at the lowest setting Nog and his crew had been able to manage when they'd rewired the system. Only his ears could pick it up, he hoped.

He destroys his ship with the hopes that it'll damage their ships enough to give the Maru a chance to coast across the border. But when he asks if he won, he's told by an instructor that "You're dead. You'll never know." To me, this doesn't quite qualify as "beating" the simulation, but it does seem like he'd get a passing grade.

---

The second victory appears in the short story *Best Tools Available*, which appears in "Strange New Worlds VI". Paul D. Waite isn't far off -- Nog makes the Romulan crew an offer:

> "Ferengi," the Romulan officer demanded, "you are in violation of intergalactic treaties and we are perfectly within our right to destroy..."
>
> "Name your price!" Nog demanded. The crew looked at him in stunned silence. Surely he did not say what they thought he had just said.

He argued with the (simulated) Romulan for a while, and then the transmission appeared to begin breaking up, and then the simulator halted entirely. Nog broke the *Kobayashi Maru* by trying to deal with it in a way it wasn't programmed to handle: the Ferengi way.

---

Actually, re-reading the stories, they *both* seem to treat this like Nog's first time taking the test, and *both* depend on him getting pivotal advice from Boothby. So I'm thinking they're alternate stories. Thanks to the fuzzy canonicity of printed Star Trek stories, they are both true and untrue.

Comment: Leave it to Federation's clueless-about-economics programmers to fail to program the AI to account for basic human behavior :)

Comment: @DVK Humanity had become a non-monetary society by then...they failed to program the AI to count for a *Ferrengi* way.

Comment: This is fantastic.  I don't know why, but it's really funny to me right now. Probably something to do with the fact that it's 2:30 in the morning.

Comment: They both exist in a quantum simultaneity until you read one or the other, upon which they collapse into canon.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens Except neither of them are ever really canon...just like the actual quantum physics, or at least that quote about it.

Comment: The second would never have worked if they just kept using Klingons